# Does nullcheck really work on a statebag?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public long MetaExtraData
{
    get { return (long)(ViewState["MetaData"] ?? 0); }
    set { ViewState["MetaData"] = value; }
}
```

When ViewBag doesn't contains the key 'MetaData' I get back a "can't cast to long" exception. Isn't the whole idea with ?? to handle this?

And of course, the below snippet will also throw a cast error. When checking the values of the variables: o=null

```
public long MetaExtraDataInt
{
    get
    {
        object o = ViewState["MetaData"];
        return (long)(o ?? 0);
    }
    set { ViewState["MetaData"] = value; }
}
```

I know the problem is easy to solve, but I really do want to know why the ?? don't work on a statebag

Comment: No, you could try to use `ViewState["MetaDataInt"] as int? ?? 0` instead.

Comment: Is it possible that `ViewState[...]` returns `DbNull` instead of `null`?

Comment: What is the value of `ViewState["MetaDataInt"]` when the exception is thrown? Also `ViewState["MetaDataInt"].GetType()`. You can check both in the `Immediate Window`.

Comment: Please don't guess - check in the `Immediate Window`.

Comment: thank you @mjwills, when trying to call ViewState["MetaDataInt"].GetType() I receive a null pointer exception and when just trying ViewState["MetaDataInt"] it is "null"

Comment: @HimBromBeere very interesting idea, but when checking in debug viewstate["foo"] seems to be a normal null. That's to bad it could have explained why ?? won't work on the statebag.

Comment: another interesting thing is this question https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7663/is-this-a-proper-way-to-check-a-viewstate-of-type-int where the accepted answer is exacly this problem

Comment: Did you try Sebastian's suggestion above?

Comment: Yes I did try @SebastianHofmann suggestion and both `ViewState["MetaDataInt"] as int? ?? 0` and `(int?)ViewState["MetaDataInt"] ?? 0` works like a charm. So.. in other words, ViewState["notfound"] does not truly returns a null or ?? does not work as expected. It's so strange it works for you guys though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `(int)(ViewState["MetaDataInt"] ?? 0)` is throwing an `InvalidCastException`, it must be because your value in the statebag isn't an `int`.

This is because:

> a boxed T can only be unboxed to T (or Nullable.) Once it is
>   unboxed, it’s just a value that can be cast as usual.

The above quote is taken from [Representation and Identity](https://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/) by Eric Lippert, which I recommend you read.

So if you are storing a type that is anything other than `int` or `int?` in your "MetaDataInt" statebag entry, you will get an invalid cast exception, even if that value is something that could cast to int.

For example, if it contains a decimal, then you can only unbox it as a decimal.  After that, you can cast as you normally would.

The following will work in the example scenario of unboxing a decimal:

```
return (int)(decimal)(ViewState["MetaDataInt"] ?? 0)
```

I suggest you look at the type of `ViewState["MetaDataInt"]` in the debugger, and alter your cast accordingly.

## Edit:

I can see what's going on.  In your screenshot, you're attempting to unbox to a long, but your coalesced zero is an int.  This is why you're getting an exception.

The following will fix your specific problem.

```
return (long)(ViewState["ParentID"] ?? 0L)
```

Note the `0L`, this is how you write a long as a numeric literal.

You're having the issue because you're coalescing the 0 `int` with a null `object`, so the result of that coalesce is also an object, in this case a boxed `int`.  A boxed `int` can only be unboxed to an `int`, but you're attempting to unbox it to a `long`.  We fix this by boxing a 0 `long` instead, so you can unbox it to a long.

Comment: @[doctor jones] You're so right, it would be nicer to have a null point exception. But I promise you ;) check my debug, I don't have the key in my collection: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pguvim5ky2qdvzg/viewstate%20nullpoint%20exception.png?dl=0

Comment: @stebberg, I have updated my answer based on your feedback

Comment: Here is working example of the behavior https://dotnetfiddle.net/UPjorI

Comment: @stebberg Here is an even more applicable version https://dotnetfiddle.net/sm2SfU

Comment: hmm... that's so strange! As @DoctorJones says converting the second part to long will do it `long l = (long)(ViewState["ParentID"] ?? Convert.ToInt64(0));` or of course as suggested nicer `long l = (long)(ViewState["ParentID"] ?? 0L);` To be honest I still don't understand why this works, I have to read your answer again and really think this through.. MANY thanks @DoctorJones

Comment: The way I will do for now is like this though: `long l = (long?)ViewState["ParentID"] ?? 0;`
It makes most sence to me.

Comment: @Jodrell thanx for the examples. I have to look into that, I did not realize, I think, that int i=1 and object o=1 is different things... hmm, or yes I did but.. anyways, thank you

Comment: @stebberg, you don't need the cast to a nullable, you can cast straight out to a long, because you've supplied the default value of zero.  The value can never be null, so there's no point in using nullable if you don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Nullable<int>` property instead of normal `int` to cast with null-coalescing operator:

```
public int? MetaExtraDataInt
{
    get { return (int?)ViewState["MetaDataInt"] ?? 0; }
    set { ViewState["MetaDataInt"] = value; }
}
```

Based from operator precedence, the null-coalescing is performed after cast to `Nullable<int>`, so that it returns zero when `ViewState["MetaDataInt"]` contains null value.

Comment: thank you Tetsuya, but I need to have this property as int and not int?

Comment: It depends on how you want to use it, I recommends `Nullable<int>` as return type if you want to contain null values, otherwise `int` should be enough.

Comment: hmm, but I don't want to cast a null to an int, that's why I have the ?? check first and then I do the cast

Comment: I honestly don't think the null-check and the convert is in the wrong order here, Unless the ?? messes up how the logic of parentheses works of course

Comment: Many thanks @Jodrell I actually have no problem to solve the problem, I just want to know why ?? don't work on a statebag

Comment: Hi @Jodrell but the convert should never need to handle a null if the ?? work properly